# This command to pipe results and search for uppercase letters is not working. Getting "no such file or directory" error

Tags: grep

I am doing an assignment and there is a part that says to put in this command that is supposed to pipe results and search for uppercase letters.

Here is the command it says to put in:

```
grep -E "[a-z]" rawpassword.txt | grep – E "[A-Z]" >passwd.txt
```

but whenever I put it in I get the error "[A-Z]": No such file or directory.

Is there a typo in the command or something?

Comment: The part on the left has `-E`, while on the right it has `- E`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Fixed that but still getting the error “[A-Z]”: No such file or directory so it seems something is wrong with the A-Z as well

Comment: that's strange, perhaps try `grep '[a-z]' rawpassword.txt | grep '[A-Z]'`

Comment: @Sundeep that works, but does it have the same effect as the other command? Just wondering since ">passwd.txt" isn't included in this one

Comment: you'd need `>passwd.txt` to save the output to that file, I just gave a suggestion to try to narrow down the issue... I think it is probably because of double quotes (or the weird version of the double quotes) you used.. and some setting/feature on your computer trying to match filenames even when `[A-Z]` was quoted

Comment: @Sundeep I changed the quotes and it still doesn't work so that's not it. For some reason it just thinks A-Z is a filename it seems, not sure how to fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### suggestion 1:

```
  grep "[a-z]" rawpassword.txt | grep  "[A-Z]" >passwd.txt
```

#### suggestion 2:

```
  awk '/[a-z]/ && /[A-Z]/' rawpassword.txt >passwd.txt
```